# Let $X = \{1,2,3,4, 5\}$ and $\mathcal{A}= \{ A : A \subset X, \#A=4 \}$. Show that the topology generated by $\mathcal{A}$ on $X$ is discrete.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X = \{1,2,3,4, 5\}$ and $\mathcal{A}= \{ A : A \subset X, \#A=4 \}$. Show that the topology generated  by $\mathcal{A}$ on $X$ is the discrete one.

So $\mathcal{A}$ consists of subsets of $X$ with $4$ elements each. I know that we can get a basis from a subbase by taking finite intersections of the elements of the subbase and that if the basis elements are singletons, then the topology on $X$ would be the discrete one. I have trouble expressing the basis as the intersections of elements of $\mathcal{A}$, how can I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subbasis for a topology on $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ whose union equals $X$, hence $\mathcal{A}$ is a subbasis for a given topology. The topology generated by the subbasis $\mathcal{A}$ is defined to be the collection $\tau$ of all unions of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{A}$.

Pick all finite intersections of the elements in $\mathcal{A}$: you get for sure the singletons $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{5\} $, where for example you get $\{1\}$ as intersection of all the $4-$element sets that contain the element $1$. Hence the basis you built from the subbasis contains the singletons, hence the generated topology is the discrete one.

Comment: Are you saying that the intersection of the $4$ element sets are always singletons? What if I have for example $\{1,2,4,5\} \cap \{2,3,5,1\} = \{2,5,1\}$ this is not a singleton.

Comment: No, I am saying that by intersecting all four element sets there is always a way to get the singletons. As I wrote above: you get $\{1\}$ as intersection of all the $4-$element sets that contain the element $1$, and in a similar way you get $\{2\}$ as intersection of all the $4-$element sets that contain the element $2$, and so on. Of course you can get even other sets, but you can always get the singletons and this is all what you need. This is enough: a basis that contains all the singletons (and maybe even more) gives you the discrete topology.

Comment: @LocomotRagsarhe He says (correctly) that $\{i\}=\bigcap\{A \in \mathcal A\mid i \in A\}$ for all $i \in X$. As this is a finite intersection, all singletons are in the generated base.

Answer (score 0):

$\{1\}=\{1,2,3,4\}\cap\{1,2,3,5\}\cap\{1,2,4,5\}\cap\{1,3,4,5\}$